# PHP how to join to records from array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi it is any way to connect to records where value is the same?

like

```
[12]=> Array (
 [ID] => 127078
 [row1] => 
 [post] => N16 7UJ
)

[13]=> Array (
 [ID] => 127078
 [row1] => something
 [post] =>
)
```

and make like that

```
[12]=> Array (
 [ID] => 127078
 [row1] => something
 [post] => N16 7UJ
)
```

Comment: Just "write the code" I'm afraid. Use `foreach` to loop, inspect if you want to join, and then build your wished item/array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here take this function

```
<?php

$array = array(
                12 => array (
                 "ID" => '127078',
                 "row1" => '',
                 "post" => 'N16 7UJ',
                ),

                13 => array (
                 "ID" => '127078',
                 "row1" => 'something',
                 "post" => '',
                )

            );
function mergedup($array,$matcher){
    if(!function_exists('remove_element')){
        function remove_element($arr,$element){
            $ret_arr = array();
            foreach($arr as $val){
                if($val !== $element){
                    array_push($ret_arr,$val);
                }
            }
            return $ret_arr;    
        }
    }
    $array = remove_element($array,array());
    $return_array = array();

    while(isset($array[0])){
        $temp = $array[0];
        $array = remove_element($array,$temp);
        $array_temp = array();
        foreach($array as $vals){
            if($temp[$matcher]==$vals[$matcher]){
                array_push($array_temp,$vals);
                foreach($temp as $key => $val){
                    if(empty($temp[$key])){
                        $temp[$key] = $vals[$key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        foreach($array_temp as $vals){
            $array = remove_element($array,$vals);
        }
        array_push($return_array,$temp);
    }

    return $return_array;
}

var_dump(mergedup($array,"ID"));
?>
```

Tested and working

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["ID"]=> string(6) "127078" ["row1"]=> string(9) "something" ["post"]=> string(7) "N16 7UJ" } }     output on my machine

Answer (score 0):

You have so many option such as `array_replace`
`array_merge`
`foreach`
`while`
`Iterator`

But i prefer `array_replace` because you can easily select which array is replacing which

Values

```
$array[12] = array("ID"=>127078,"row1"=>"","post"=>"N16 7UJ");
$array[13] = array("ID"=>127078,"row1"=>"something","post"=>"");
var_dump($array[12]);
```

Example `array_replace` ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php )

```
$array[13] = array_filter($array[13]); //Filter Replacement
$array[12]= array_replace($array[12],$array[13]);
```

Example `array_merge` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php )

```
//$array[12] = array_filter($array[12]); //Optinal 
$array[13] = array_filter($array[13]); //Filter Spaces
$array[12]= array_merge($array[12],$array[13]);
var_dump($array[12]);
```

Output

```
array
  'ID' => int 127078
  'row1' => string 'something' (length=9)
  'post' => string 'N16 7UJ' (length=7)
```

Comment: You'd have to check out if you want it for 11/12 or 12/13, what the result is, etc...

Comment: I did not think that would be a problem .. but corrected ...  @Nanne

Comment: I'm assuming he has a big array with (at least) 13 parts. If you now you want to join 12 and 13, sure, but if you just have 1 to 100 and "want to join some"), you'd have to just.. well.. write it. Check if you want it, and then you could in the end use merge obviously :)

Comment: +1 for good point but look at his values ... i notice empty space could be issue that is why i added `array_filter` .. but i'Ll update the code to have merge ..tooo thanks